# Subversion non transitive merge

Tags: svn, merge

I currently struggle with the following scenario:

- We do most of our development in trunk
- We have separate branches for certain features which are experimental and not production ready yet.
- We regularly merge changes from trunk to the branches due to dependencies and for easier reintegration later
- We have two release branches, one for production and one for experimental packages
- In the experimental release branch, we reintegrate feature1 and feature2
- Due to the nature of subversion, we need to block the merges from trunk->feature1 and trunk->feature2, otherwise the changes from trunk are conflicting itself when reintegrating to the experimental release branch

**Now to my problem:**

When I change something in trunk

```
cd trunk
svn commit -m "Foo"
[...]
Committed revision 4
```

Then I synchronize the change from trunk to feature1 with

```
cd feature1
svn merge ^/trunk
[...]
Committed revision 5
```

then I try to block the merge from revision 5 in the experimental release branch with

```
cd experimental
svn merge ^/branches/feature1 -r5 --record-only
```

the revision trunk:4 and feature:5 are marked as blocked. However I only want to block feature:5

**TL;DR: Is there a way to turn off transitive merge blocking in subversion?**

Comment: I managed to get to my desired result by reverse merging the same revision while ignoring ancestry:
svn merge --record-only -c 5 ^/branches/feature1
svn merge --record-only --ignore-ancestry -r 5:4 ^/branches/feature1
svn commit -m "Blocking revision 5"
However, this does not feel like a clean solution. Hopefully, somebody else stumbles across my question and has some better idea...